# Project disappears after getting latest version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, source-control-explorer

Background: I have a solution in Visual Studio 2013 with several projects that I have synced with Team Foundation Server. Myself and one other programmer are the only ones who regularly work on this solution.  Two of the projects have corresponding setup projects which only I work with.  We had problems with keeping the setup projects synced between our computers because sometimes it would update on his which would break mine because of file references or maybe because I am using an obfuscation tool he doesn't have.  For this reason, he has cloaked the setup projects in his Source Control so that I can sync them with TFS, but he won't have to see them and to eliminate the issue stated above.

Question.  Now, when I get the latest changes to the solution, the setup projects disappear out of my Solution Explorer and I have to readd them.  I can go to Source Control and see these setup projects, but I can't figure out how to fix this so that it doesn't remove my setup projects when I get the latest solution version.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both of you opening the same solution with different projects.

When he opens the solution he will see two dead projects (the cloaked setup ones) and he is removing them from the solution. Then when you get the solution they are missing.

All developers working on a solution must get all the bits. A work around for this I to create a new solution file in the same folder as the other one. This solution only has the non-setup projects. You open the main solution and he opens the cut down version.